# Moving From Point A to B on Map (Google maps or any other map )

Tags: google-maps, maps, openmap

I would like to move between two addresses in **Google maps** however i do not have the Geo coordinate latlng (latlng range) for this movement. I can select two addresses from a list which i can make the marker move between. Basically i want to show movement between two locations.

Is it possible that i can ask **Google maps** for a list of all location names on its map?
Like in this [example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_animate_marker_directions.html) but i would like to provide a drop down list of all existing addresses in that country

Comment: Do you mean something like [this](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_animate_marker_directions.html)

Comment: yes just like that however i want to randomly set the start and destination so may be store the start and destination in a database

Comment: I was looking at the code for that however like i say i want to find a way to select random paths A to C or F to A but i need to know what paths exist how can i assemble all that possible paths on the map in terms of actually address names not long lat coordinates

Comment: I dont know if there exist some function that can loop through the map and assemble location info like place name addresses and store them in lets say a database or do i need to manually store paths

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Why would you want to save random paths?

Comment: well i did use an algorithm to off set lat long coordinates. I used the haversine formula, however when my markers move i get a blink effect while moving if you know what i mean. However i saw that example you send me and i liked the smooth path movement

I realized and correct me if i am wrong but smooth movement wroks well for already defined paths. I am trying to simulate random paths yes but i want it to be along road paths

Comment: My algorithm allows movement anywhere which is ok but i have to do alot more work to prevent it form going off the map and i dont think i can address the blinking effect unless i generate a random path thats long enough and attempt a smooth transition

Comment: Why would it need to be along a road? [example on a polyline from xml](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_animate_marker_xml.html)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29627/discussion-between-dev-darin-and-geocodezip)

Comment: You still haven't explained _why_ you want to do this, which makes it really difficult to answer your question(s) [and you should really only ask one answerable question at a time]

Comment: ok sorry about that  i will update the question

Comment: i updated the question to address one concern

Comment: @geocodezip my question was modified can you assist?

Comment: The answer to your question as not formulated is no. You can't as Google Maps for a list of all location names on its map, that is against the terms of use. You can get lists like that from Open Street Maps and/or geonames.org (an in the US from the census tiger data), it just might not be consistent with the map displayed by Google.

Comment: @geocodezip you can post this as your answer so i can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question as formulated is no. You can't use Google Maps for a list of all location names on its map, that is against the [terms of use](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#tos). You can get lists like that from [Open Street Maps](http://www.openstreetmap.org/) and/or [geonames.org](http://www.geonames.org) (an in the US from the census tiger data), it just might not be consistent with the map displayed by Google.